# Custom Url Rewriting in php

Tags: mysql, url-rewriting

I am implementing a basic URL rewriting in a php application. Below is the approach I am following:

```
table 1: rewrite_table (fields as below)

id | original_url | custom_url
```

This table I am using to store original URL and custom url.

I am checking in starting whether requested url is matched with any custom_url and if yes then I am calling controller and action which is being saved in original_url field

which is working fine. Now, point is if I change the custom url again then I want to keep the old url in a url log table and in case any user browse the webpage with that old url then (s)he will be redirect to new url with 301 redirect.

I have created a new table as

```
Table2: rewrite_table (fields as below)

log_original_url | current_url_id (this belongs to first table id filed)
```

This table I am using to store old URL which is publically accessible to all before updating the url again which was already in 1st table.

I am confusing and unable to find any solution to implement the second approach.

Anyone can help me to find out a solution

Thanks

Comment: Any reason for doing it that way rather than just using .htaccess? (Or web.config if you're on IIS)

Comment: Yes John, some times we need to add custom urls randomly and to get rid of adding rule in htaccess every time to match condition

Answer (score 0):

By your question,it seems that you are using original_url  in all cases.

My approach for this will be.

select   T1.original_url from rewritetable1 T1 Left Join rewritetable2 T2 on T2.current_url_id=T1.id
     where   T1.custom_url='user input url' OR 
             T2.log_original_url ='user input url'

So if user enter the old custom url or new custom url ,u will getting original_url which you are gonna redirect

Comment: Thanks Mohana,But I have already tried this approach.

Think of in case when there be duplicate entry in log table 
OR
record not matched in first table then we need to search in second table separately to confirm for is there any old url for the request and if yes then we have to find the original url based on the id saved in log table 2 

here one more case will generate if duplicate entry in log table. then first matched records will be fetched and respective original url return.

Comment: i think when saving custom url you need to insert a new row in Table2 which maps original_url_id  with old_custom_url.But you are now saving original_url itself instead of custom url .If change when saving accordingly my edited answer might work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**table 1: urls (internal_url is unique)**

id | internal_url | current_alias_id

---

1  | user/index   | 3

2  | user/view    | 4

**table 2: aliases (alias is unique)**

id | internal_url_id | alias

---

1  | 1   | /my/custom/index/url/1

2  | 1   | /my/custom/index/url/2

3  | 1   | /my/custom/index/url/3

4  | 2   | /my/custom/view/url/1

The examples above illustrate a situation where each internal (in your terms "original") url can have one or more aliases. One of these aliases is always "current" or "canonical". When visited, it must be rewritten to the corresponding internal url, with no redirection happening. Internal URL always points to its canonical alias via the "current_alias_id" field. The other aliases, when visited, must be redirected to the "canonical" alias of the same internal URL.

In the examples, internal url "user/index" has 3 aliases, and its current (canonical) alias is #3, while the other 2 are "old".

The internal url "user/view" has only one alias #4, which is also canonical.

The required behavior, if I understand you properly, can be achieved with the following pseudo code:

```
record = SELECT a.*, 
         u.current_alias_id, u.internal_url 
         c.alias AS canonical_alias
         FROM `aliases` a
         INNER JOIN `urls` u ON a.original_url_id = u.id
         INNER JOIN `aliases` c ON u.current_alias_id = c.id
         WHERE a.alias = '$request_url';

// assume we found a record
if (record.id == record.current_alias_id)
    // rewrite to record.internal_url
else 
    // redirect to record.canonical_alias
```

Should you need to add a new alias, for example, to internal URL #2 (user/view) - just add it to the aliases table, where it will receive id = 5, and then `UPDATE urls SET current_alias_id = 5 WHERE urls.id = 2`

From now on, whoever visits the new alias, the request will be rewritten directly, and whoever visits the old alias #4, will be redirected to url #5.

Of course you should enforce that each "internal url" and each "alias" is unique, by setting a "unique" index on the corresponding columns.

Comment: Hi Sergey,

Thanks for your detailed solution. 

I would like to mention that this approach will not handle the case when a user will use a cached/saved URL and system has already been updated with a new alias URL.

Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

Thank you so much for your efforts...

Comment: Why do you think so? This algorithm can receive request for any alias, whether old or new. It will always redirect to the alias that is marked as  "current" in the "urls" table. As a result, user's cache will be updated to point to the new redirect.